# f() values at end points not of opposite sign

Tags: r, uniroot

I am trying to get the inverse of cdf and use it for the QQ plot as follows.

```
cdf<-function(x,b){
  1 - (1+(b*x*(b*x+2)/(b^2+2)))*exp(-b*x)
}

qf<-function(p,b){
  uniroot(function(x) cdf(x,b) - p, lower=0, upper=1000)[1]
}

DATA1<-c(14, 13, 19, 22, 11,17)

dakash <- function(x,b) (b^3/(b^2+2))*(1+x^2)*exp(-b*x)
pakash <- function(q,b) (1 - (1+(b*q*((b*q)+2)/(b^{2}+2)))*exp(-b*q))
qakash <- function(p,b) qf(p,b)



fitgumbel <- fitdist(DATA1, "akash", start=list(b=5))

qqcomp(list(fitgumbel),legendtext=c("akash"))
```

But I get the following error.

> Error in uniroot(function(x) cdf(x, b) - p, lower = 0, upper = 1,
> extendInt = "yes") :  f() values at end points not of opposite sign

Please anyone can help me?
Thank you in advance.

I need to plot Q-Q plot Empirical quantiles vs Theoretical quantiles.

Comment: The error is telling you function is not crossing the X axis in the given range.  You should try plotting the function to see if you can estimate the root.  It may be possible that the search range is too large but I suspect the function does not contain a root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that the parameter `b` is strictly positive. An easy way of doing that is the substitution `b = exp(beta)`:

```
cdf<-function(x,beta){
  1 - (1+(exp(beta)*x*(exp(beta)*x+2)/(exp(beta)^2+2)))*exp(-exp(beta)*x)
}

curve(cdf(x, log(5)), to = 1)

qf<-function(p,beta){
  uniroot(function(x) cdf(x, beta) - p, lower=0, upper=1000)$root
}

abline(v = qf(.5, log(5)), lty = 2)
abline(h = 0.5, lty = 2)
#works correctly


DATA1<-c(14, 13, 19, 22, 11,17)

dakash <- function(x,beta) (exp(beta)^3/(exp(beta)^2+2))*(1+x^2)*exp(-exp(beta)*x)
pakash <- function(q, beta) cdf(q, beta)
qakash <- function(p,beta) Vectorize(qf)(p, beta)

library(fitdistrplus)

fitgumbel <- fitdist(DATA1, "akash", start=list(beta=log(5)))

setNames(exp(fitgumbel$estimate), "b")
#        b 
#0.1853882 

qqcomp(list(fitgumbel),legendtext=c("akash"))
```

[image: resulting qq-plot]